# Cutting a toast sandwich, or how to split a square using single, straight cuts minimizing the with of each piece

Tags: geometry

This is something I think about every time I eat sandwiches made with toast: how should I cut my sandwich so that each piece I cut has all sides narrower than my mouth.

The condition is I can only use single, straight cuts, that is, all cuts must split the remaining sandwich into exactly two pieces, and I eat one of them. This process continues until the last piece has sides small enough to eat, at which point I'm done.

Usually, I start by cutting off a triangle like this:

[image]

Next, I do the same thing on the other side, like this:

[image]

Followed by something like this:

[image]

These three cuts more or less continue a couple of times, until the top side of the sandwich is within reach. However, that third cut is where it always gets tricky because if I do the first two cuts too small, in order to make the hypotenuse of those triangle pieces as small as possible, I and up with a trapezoid piece with a large side that I have trouble fitting in, usually ending with ketchup smeared all over by face.

So, what series of cuts should I use to get the most manageable bites and how wide will I need to open my mouth (relative to the square side length)?

Comment: This is a bit vague. You need some kind of collection of cutting rules, and a quantification of what "small enough" is to mean.